# How to get the xapth of a dropdown element when removing event listeners and freezing the page don't work

Tags: xpath, drop-down-menu, dropdown

So I have a dropdown with two items. When I open the dropdown and right-click on either of the elements to get it's xpath, the dropdown closes. I know two methods here:

1- Navigate to the sources tab, and pausing the page by pressing F8
2- Removing the `blur` event listener.

Non of these work and immediately after each click or right click or key press, the dropdown closes. What should I do?